# How are the results for count different in all these three cases?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

Code 1:

```
iteration = 0

count = 0

while iteration < 5:

    for letter in "hello, world":

        count += 1

    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)

    iteration += 1
```

Code 2:

```
iteration = 0

while iteration < 5:

    count = 0

    for letter in "hello, world":

        count += 1

    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)

    iteration += 1
```

Code 3:

```
iteration = 0

while iteration < 5:

    count = 0

    for letter in "hello, world":

        count += 1

        if iteration % 2 == 0:

            break

    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)

    iteration += 1
```

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Have you tried running them?

Comment: Yes, I do not understand why he value of count is different in the first case where iteration changes while in the second case, even the iteration changes the count is the same.

Comment: Count gets initialised to 0 inside the iteration loop in second scenario. In the first case, count is initialised outside the loop.

Comment: Oh yeah but in third code, the count changes even when it is inside the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Code 1**, you're continuing to add on to the count. So during the first iteration, the count becomes 12 (the length of "hello, world" is 12), and then during the second iteration, you never reset the count to 0 so count is continuously added on until it reaches 24, as it adds on the length of "hello, world" again (12 + 12 = 24).

```
0 + len("hello, world") = 12

12 + len("hello, world") = 24

and so forth
```

For **Code 2**, count is reset to 0 each time. This means that the count will always equal 12, as the length of "hello, world" is 12.

```
0 + len("hello, world") = 12

reset to 0 

0 + len("hello, world") = 12

and so forth
```

For **Code 3**, you break every time the iteration is an even number. That means for iterations 0, 2, and 4, iteration returns a value of 1 as 1 is added to iteration at the beginning of the for loop. But during odd iterations, the count is 12, since the program does not break out of the for loop and adds the length of "hello, world", which is 12.

```
count = 0

For loop
     "h" in "hello, world"

     Add 1, 0 -> Is it even or odd? Even, Do not add len("ello, world") to count

1

count = 0

For loop
     "h" in "hello, world"

     Add 1, 0 -> Is it even or odd? Odd, Do add len("ello, world") to count

12
```

Comment: So, what I don't understand is that in the second and third code, even when the count is inside the while loop, why doesn't it change in second code but it changes in third code?

Comment: @Eliza It changes in the third code because you added an if statement checking whether iteration is odd or not. If the iteration is odd, you add the lenght of "hello, world", which is 12. If it is even, as indicated by the if statement, you break out of the forloop and print out the count, which is 1, because you added 1 before the if statement.

Comment: Ok, so, the purpose of break is to come out of if and go to the for loop, right? and then re-start the count. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Code 1:

Your count is set outside the `while` loop, therefore it is not effected by it and thus increase by 12 `len(hello, world) = 12`

Code 2:

Your count is inside the `while` loop, therefore it resets with each iteration ONLY. That's why `count = 12` is staying the same while `Iteration`, being outside the loop, increases.

Code 3:

When your `Iteration` is even the code is breaking after the first count. When it's odd it runs through the code fine.

Answer (score 0):

In code 1 during every iteration, you are adding value of `count` to the previous one. While in the code 2, at the beginning of every iteration, you are re-assigning the `count = 0`. In each iteration, after the for loop is executed, 12 is added to the previous value of count which in case of code 2 is always `0`. Hence value of count is different in both the case.

In case 3, after the execution of for loop, either you count value will be 1 (if the value of iteration is even) or 12 (if the value of iteration is odd). This is because of the if condition that check for the i%2. Hence in case 3, value of count is different for odd and even. And since during each iteration you are reassigning `count = 0`, value of count for all odd number is 12 and value of count for all even number is 1.

Comment: I think I understand it now. But, how does count = 1 when iteration = 0. Here, 0 is neither odd nor even?